# Turn-based Game Loop

Tags: actionscript, game-engine

I am having a lot of headache trying to make a game loop in Actionscript. Searched a lot and could not to find the answer. My idea is:

When de game starts, it defined the units sequence of attack, based in their speed (each player can have until 8 units, of any kind). I store this sequence into an Array. I did create the engine in Javascript returning the values in console.log... and works fine... but transporting it to AS3, the things aren't working as I thought.

So... I have the sequence... and now I do the loop
This is my logic (not using any specific language):

```
for (i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {

    isHitting = sequence[i]; // first unit from list is the hitter
    isDefending = mostPowerfulEnemy(); // method to check who will be attacked

    // here is the problem!!!!
    isHitting.moveTo(isDefending); // method to move the MC near the target

    var kills = isHitting.hit(isDefending); // calc the damage and return the kills

    if (isDefending.amount <= 0) {
        // remove the MC from Stage and the sequence list
       continue; //to move to the next hitter in sequence

    } else {

       isDefending.amount -= kills;
       continue; //to move to the next hitter in sequence
    }
}
```

The problem is: all units are moving at same time!
I've learning about Events and the method addEventListener() sounds like the best option, but i have to call a function, right? I do it... so the unit move to the point... hit... and stop... I need a way to say: "hey, this unit already did his move, did stop and did hit the target, you can now continue the loop" (since I cant return a continue, ofc)

This is what I want:

[image: animation]

Some suggestion?
Sorry my bad english.

Comment: This is what I want to do... look so simple =(
http://phpfromhell.com/GameMechanics/Answer.gif

Comment: The image doesn't make things more clear to me. Basically it sounds like you have a list of actions that you want to proceed in a timed manner (incl. waiting for animations to happen). To wirte code that can do this I assume you would need to understand how the AVM2 (aka FlashPlayer) works internally, which I assume is different from the browsers rendering engine. This is a good start:http://www.craftymind.com/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/ While reading this might help to understand whats going on, maybe you want to look at what frameworks are already there to help you.

Comment: I guess what I want to say is: how can I stop my main loop while the motion tween of that object moving is not done?

Comment: the most simple way you can try, which might not be the most performant one and might contradict best practices in this topic, would be to have a method `function onFrame(event:Event)` that you use as an event handler calling `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame)` and treat the body of the method like the body of a `for loop`: check if the animations are done: when not `return;` (waiting for the next frame to call your method again) otherwise do the next action in your list. There is no (other) way to pause code execution then to go async in AS3. (code execution time != rendering time)

Comment: So ... I'm almost there, using a recursive function that calls addEventListeners. But not ready yet. It is my personal project and I have not had much time lately. Thank you.

Comment: I do not see why you should call eventlisteners your self or even recursively, flash is doin this for you. I created a small example using the approach I suggested: If you understand how it works maybe its easier for you to create what you want: http://wonderfl.net/c/cB3Y